# Как вывести всю информацию из списка?

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py

```
async def rb(ctx):
    r = requests.get('https://tanksblitz.ru/ru/api/rating-leaderboards/league/0/top/', headers = HEADERS)
    data = r.json()
    for d in data['result']:
        a = d['clan_tag']
        b = d['nickname']
        c = d['score']
    await ctx.send(a)
    await ctx.send(b)
    await ctx.send(c)

Выводится только последе значение из списка, как сделать так чтобы выводились все. Также как можно вывести это в виде таблице, например:
1. ['clan_tag'] ['nickname'] ['score']
2. ['clan_tag'] ['nickname'] ['score']
и так далее

Ожидал, что выведется так:
['clan_tag'] ['nickname'] ['score']

Но выводится так:
['clan_tag']
['nickname']
['score']
```

Comment: попробуйте поднять все три `await` в цикл `for`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Форматируй строковую переменную, чтобы она была на одной линии.
С форматированием можно ещё тэг обвести квадратными скобками и т.п.

```python
for d in data['result']:
    await ctx.send('[{}]{} — {}'.format(*(d[i] for i in ['clan_tag','nickname','score'])))
```

###### Вывод:

```
[PWNZ]Luc1que_ — 6572
[CONTX]boonchlchi — 6478
[2XX]perdyyn — 6421
…
[M_E_F]Smisterr — 5903
[]JlerKo_u_I7p0cTo — 5898
[ABQBA]yanakrzh — 5883
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! А можно сделать так, чтобы выводилось только первые 10?

Comment: @sssaaayyyuuu `for d in data['result'][:10]`